# Horizontal Scroll Bar For Morris Chart Bar Graph

Tags: html, bar-chart, raphael, morris.js

I am using morris bar charts previously I had no issues regarding it but i decided to check it with  large data set and now my graph looks like this
[Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzDIA.png)

I have searched number of platforms for the solution but apparently morris chart doesn't give the scrolling option.

Is there a workaround for this problem? or do i have to use different graph which i would prefer not to do as i have invested so much time on making this.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a CSS property `min-width` to the div containing your chart. Example `min-width: 1300px;`